# Setting up an .inputrc file with set commands in mac bash

Tags: macos, bash

I'm trying to improve my bash experience by adding the usual preferences to the `inputrc` file:

```
set completion-ignore-case on
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
TAB: menu-complete
```

However, when I put them in my `etc/.inputrc` file and restart bash, they don't work. Is `etc/` the proper place for the `.inputrc` file? I believe you need to create the file from scratch on a Mac. I couldn't find one so I made it myself. Is there another set command I need to copy/paste into my `.inputrc` file to make these other commands work?

Edit: I created a new `.inputrc` file in my home directory with the same commands and Bash accepted it. I thought this file needed to be in `/etc`. Would love an explanation if anyone has one.

Answer (score 3):

> I created a new `.inputrc` file in my home directory with the same commands and Bash accepted it. I thought this file needed to be in `/etc`. Would love an explanation if anyone has one.

Bash uses `readline` and `man readline` says:

> INITIALIZATION FILE
>   Readline is customized by putting commands in an initialization file (the `inputrc` file). The name of this file is taken from the value of the `INPUTRC` environment variable. If that variable is unset, the default is `~/.inputrc`. If that file does not exist or cannot be read, the ultimate default is `/etc/inputrc`. […]

So the relevant file is `~/.inputrc` or `/etc/inputrc`. The file you tried (`/etc/.inputrc`) is never mentioned.